# Sort by node or comment

Tags: views

We have a Question and Answer setup on Drupal. Question is a node. The answer is a comment.

What we are trying to do is to order Questions by either the latest asked question or by the latest commented question.

So when a new comment it posted, that questions moves on top. I can do it for Question or comments. But can't combine the two together.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you were building the SQL directly, you could do it in the `ORDER BY` clause with the [`CASE WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) syntax where you do something like:

`CASE WHEN comment_table.timestamp > node_table.timestamp then comment_table.timestamp else node_table.timestamp`

Since there is no default Views core plugin for `CASE WHEN` sorting, you can either build a [Views sort plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21sort%21SortPluginBase.php/group/views_sort_handlers/8.5.x) that implements the syntax or use existing plugins that [allow custom SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_raw_sql) with a notable security caveat that comes with storing code in your configuration.